# question about whether $f$ gets closer to $Li(x)$ over a certain range

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I came up with a prime counting function which counts primes and reciprocals of primes in an alternating way:

$$f(x)=\sum_{p_k\le x}  \exp( (-1)^{k +1}/\log p_k)$$

I did some analysis and found that seems like $f(x)\sim Li(x)$ the logarithmic integral.

[desmos code showing f(x) getting closer to Li(x)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eqtfrqlpxb).

But it seems from my analysis and data that there could be a *much stronger statement.* $f(x)$ might actually get *closer and closer* to $Li(x)$ in the sense that the differences between them *decrease* at least over a small range.

I'm almost certain this has to be completely wrong. Have I just not plotted enough values to see my observation fail?

> Does $f$ get closer to $Li(x)?$ Does this hold only for a certain range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PNT: $$\forall r >0,\qquad \pi(x)=Li(x)+o(\frac{x}{\log^r x})$$
$$\sum_{p\le x} \frac1{\log^r p} =
(1+o(1))\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1/\log n}{\log^r n}= \frac{x}{\log^{r+1} x} +o(\frac{x}{\log^{r+1} x})$$
So that
$$f(x)=\pi(x)+\sum_{p^k\le x} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\log p_k}+\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{2 \log^2 p}+O(\sum_{p\le x}\frac1{\log^3 p}) $$ $$
= (Li(x)+ o(\frac{x}{\log^3 x}))+O(1)+( \frac{x}{2\log^3 x} +o(\frac{x}{\log^3 x}))+O(\frac{x}{\log^4 x})$$
$$ = Li(x)+\frac{x}{2\log^3 x} +o(\frac{x}{\log^3 x})$$

Comment: updated question

Comment: I don't think this is quite right

Comment: @geocalc33 Looking at your numerical experiment I realize that you meant something very weird with the sign $\pm $ depending on $p$. Please clarify your question with $f(x)=\sum_{p_k\le x}  \exp( (-1)^{k +1}/\log p_k)$ and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: done thanks for updating your answer